# When did the file mode in Perl's open become a separate argument?

Tags: perl, changelog

Once upon a time, you opened files in Perl like so:

```
open(FH, ">$filename");
```

At some point, for many good reasons including some very sticky ones involving filenames with leading spaces, this syntax became available (and, immediately, preferred):

```
open(FH, '>', $filename);
```

What version of Perl did we get that syntax with?

Comment: "open my $fh, '>', $filename or die $!" is even more preferred.

Comment: That isn't really just the `open` operation, though, that's the `open` operation plus a form of failure handling that may or may not be appropriate to context.  I only wanted to talk about `open`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you posted this question & answer? There are lots of changes documented in perldelta and no reason for SO to duplicate those one at a time...

Comment: I posted it because I was having a hard time finding it.  I answered it because I found it.

Comment: Also, consider me to have said something rude and aggressive here, because that's what I really feel like doing in response to the tone of your comment.

Comment: @eugene y: I started to edit my question to reflect the `my $fh` syntax, then realized (as related research had turned up) that that syntax actually became valid at the same time as the three-argument `open`.  So mucking with that would just confuse the issue.

Comment: I see your something rude and aggressive and raise you an arrogant and abusive reply. Seriously, I assumed you knew about perldelta and was curious what made this question special. Being unable to find a particular needle in one of a dozen haystacks is a perfectly valid answer. It can be a challenge to find the *when* for a particular *what*.

Comment: In that vein, I've found `corelist` (http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-CoreList/) invaluable for telling me what version of Perl contains a given module.  E.g. `corelist /File::Spec/` from the command line.  Very handy when you're trying to figure out which additional modules you need to install on some other computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have those sorts of questions, start crawling back through the *perl*delta* documents. You can mostly skip the minor versions since those versions shouldn't introduce major features.

In this case, you'd find it in [perl56delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta.html).

Comment: And for the record, Perl 5.6 was released on March 22, 2000 (http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/pod/perlhist.pod)

Answer (score 11):

Looks like [5.6.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta.html#open%28%29-with-more-than-two-arguments).

Comment: In other words, Late Jurassic :)

Comment: Some of my early professional sysadmin tasks were done in Perl 4, when it was *new and exciting*.  You kids get your "fire" and your "wheel" off my grass.

Comment: Aah, I was curious if `open my $fh, '>:raw', $filename` came about at the same time -- it appears so.

Comment: ephemient: ':raw' is an io layer, they were added in 5.8.0.

Comment: @Alexandr Ciornii: `perl56delta` says that `:raw` and `:crlf` are new in 5.6.0, though.  Perhaps not in the same form as in 5.8.0?

Comment: Although you found the answer, how you found the answer is probably the interesting part. So, what did you do? :)

Comment: Since the perl deltas aren't in a subdirectory or anything, the trick winds up being googling `site:perldoc.perl.org +"History / Changes" <what you're looking for>`.